# Are there any UML reference card available?

Tags: oop, uml

Are there any reference cards or cheats sheets available for UML?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[UML Distilled](http://books.google.com.ar/books?id=nHZslSr1gJAC&dq=uml+distilled&printsec=frontcover&source=bl&ots=V66SJXUA5C&sig=Qvp8jIzzcFLBWVulJQ0rR7_0174&hl=es&ei=itifSvDaHqaxmAe57tXdDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false) is the shortest but yet explicative guide to UML ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020165783X)).

You also have several UML Cheat Sheets:

- [UML Quick Reference Guide](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/UML%20Quick%20Reference%20Card.pdf)
- [UML Reference Card](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/UML%20Reference%20Card.pdf)
- [UML Cheatsheet](http://loufranco.com/blog/assets/cheatsheet.pdf)

Comment: The reference cards come on the flap of book covers, they are well done.

Answer (score -1):

Something like [this?](http://www.scribd.com/doc/399157/UML-20-Cheatsheet)